# Is there a way to selectively turn off USB ports on Windows 10 programatically

Tags: c++, windows, usb, controls, hardware

I believe that my question more or less covers what I am trying to do, is there any way to turn on or off windows 10 USB ports, I have several that I selectively need, yet do not want constantly connected.  I am certain that there is some sort of hardware that can do this, however, I would rather do it through a program.

Comment: What do u mean by turn off?  disable??

Comment: as in stop from being associated with the computer. for all intents and purposes creating an "air gap" if it were a network componet

Comment: I didn't get it man pls make it it clear I can help then only.

Comment: I mean, if there is a mouse or a drive or any accessory connected to a USB port, it would no longer be connected to the computer, similar to going into the registry and setting the value of USB to 4, which disables all USB ports, I want to target and disable a specific USB port.